# Why when the character is walking it's not drawing a red line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In general, I want to draw a red line in real time behind a character who is walking. The line should start from the first original character position and then to be drawn while the player is walking to mark what way the player walked so far.

Now I also want to draw a red line each time the character reached a way point. The red line will be drawn between the original character position and the first reached way point then the next time reaching the second way point to draw a line from the first way point to the second way point and so on all the way points and last line between the last way point the original character position.

But for some reason it's not drawing the lines at all. I want to draw the lines in the game window while the game is running.

Now I'm using Debug.DrawLine but it's not drawing anything. Maybe I'm not looking on the right place the Debug window ? I see the console window under the game window. Anyway i want to draw the line/s in the game window while the game is running.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    float moveSpeed = 3f;
    float rotationSpeed = 3f;
    Transform myTransform;
    State state;
    public enum State
    {
        Idle,
        Way1,
        Way2,
        Way3,
        Way4
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = transform;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Scripts Strart");
        state = State.Idle;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update");
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Idle:
                Idle();
                break;
            case State.Way1:
                waypoint1();
                break;
            case State.Way2:
                waypoint2();
                break;
            case State.Way3:
                waypoint3();
                break;
            case State.Way4:
                waypoint4();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void Idle()
    {
        state = State.Way1;
    }
    void waypoint1()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W1").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way2;
    }
    void waypoint2()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W2").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way3;
    }
    void waypoint3()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W3").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way4;
    }
    void waypoint4()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W4").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug.DrawLine only shows up in the Scene View. If you want your lines to show up ingame, you need to use a [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)

Comment: Yeah, anything from the Debug class is probably not intended to be seen from an end user's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Let try LineRenderer add one point when you move....

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html
```